# How do I get rid of the $|y-x|$ denominator?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck on this problem. I'm trying to prove the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\left(\frac{y+x}{y^2-x^2}\right)$ exists from first principles. I have got a value of $1$ for the limit via limit laws, so I know I must work towards that. Here is what I have:

$$Let f(x,y)=\frac{y+x}{y^2-x^2}\;and\;\varepsilon > 0$$
$$\therefore f(x,y)-1=\frac{y+x}{y^2-x^2}-1$$
$$\therefore |f(x,y)-1|=\left|\frac{1}{y-x}-\frac{y-x}{y-x}\right|=\left|\frac{x-(y-1)}{y-x}\right|=\frac{|x-(y-1)|}{|y-x|}\le\frac{|x|+|y-1|}{|y-x|}$$

If $|y-x| \ge 1$ then I can remove the denominator without changing the inequality. In that case, I can prove the required limit exists. However, for $|y-x|<1$, I can't do that. How should I proceed from here to complete the proof that the limit is 1?

Comment: Hint: use $y^2 - x^2 = (y - x)(y + x)$ first.

Comment: Hint: Consider an open ball about $(0,1)$ of radius $1/4$ and find an upper bound on $1/|x-y|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, let consider a disk $D$ centered at $(0,1)$ with radius $0<\delta\le\frac {1}{2}$

[image]

then for $(x,y)\in D$ we have $1-\sqrt 2\delta\le y-x \le 1+\sqrt 2\delta$ and then $\frac{|x-y+1|}{|y-x|}\le \frac{\sqrt 2\delta}{1-\sqrt 2\delta}\le5\delta$ therefore it suffices to take $\delta=\min\left(\frac {\varepsilon } 5,\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score -1):

You can complete the proof by showing that the inequality $\frac{|x|+|y-1|}{|y-x|}<\varepsilon$ is always true for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$. This inequality is true if and only if

$$|x|<\varepsilon|y-x|-|y-1|$$

Since $|y-x|<1$, this inequality is true if and only if

$$|x|<\varepsilon-|y-1|$$

For any $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $\delta=1+\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon-|y-1|<\delta$. Therefore, for any $(x,y)$ such that $|x|<\delta$ and $y\neq 1$, we have $|f(x,y)-1|<\varepsilon$, which shows that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\left(\frac{y+x}{y^2-x^2}\right)$ exists and is equal to 1.

Comment: I don't follow why $|y-x|<1$? If $y=1.1$ and $x=-0.2$, the claim is not true.